# Reset search fields to original values after POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, reset

I have a search screen in my MVC3 app, with 4 different fields that can be used for searching - a couple of drop down lists, and a couple of text fields.

The search form is submitted via a post, and the values of the fields are part of the model.  However, after the first search, the values are set as the field values, so a reset won't set to the original values.

Is there an easy way to handle this?

Comment: are you doing an ajax call to get search results ? post your code pls

Comment: Have you tried to reset the form using jQuery?